# python - plot label objects not found ... why?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I thought it's a simple code but i keep on getting this error message and i don't know why:

> UserWarning: No labelled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on
>   individual plots.   warnings.warn("No labelled objects found. "

I've seen other solutions where they said plt.legend() should directly come after the plot command...so i tried this too but it didn't work

This is the code:

```
x_multi = [int(k[-3:]) for k in data_all_bands.keys()]
colors = ['blue', 'black', 'green', 'red']
for i in range(len(list(data_all_bands.values())[0])):
    y_multi = [v[i] for v in data_all_bands.values()]
    plt_multi = axes[0].scatter(x_multi, y_multi, label="channel" , color = colors[i])#, color=colors[i])
    plt.legend()
```

The plot does appear but just without the label...in the case above it should write 4 times channel for each color.

EDIT: In order to reproduce

`data_all_bands` is a dictionary and looks like this:

```
2016050 [4.2958281793198241, 3.7025449821599157, 5.1717757645735025, 4.9954723025001719]
2016178 [4.0679016016577032, 2.890807214158575, 4.9627629940324081, 4.8505350289087952]
2016290 [3.6947496139720259, 3.1549071645707891, 4.5131724769284824, 4.4082219917836483]
2016114 [3.6302508875834567, 2.9879816559435759, 4.4887321676347716, 4.4042679859883815]
```

Comment: @DavidG same error... this is in front of Userwarning: `site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:475` though

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? I currently cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: @DavidG sure. i edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a figure with multiple subplots, but only plotting on the first one. You are also using a combination of the object oriented API (`axes.scatter`) and the pyplot state-machine (`plt.legend`).

So, when you call `plt.legend` it is looking for labels in one of your empty subplots and giving you the warning you are seeing. One solution would be to create a legend for the subplots you are plotting to using `axes[0].legend()`:

```
for i in range(len(list(data_all_bands.values())[0])):
    y_multi = [v[i] for v in data_all_bands.values()]
    plt_multi = axes[0].scatter(x_multi, y_multi, label="channel" , color = colors[i])#, color=colors[i])
    axes[0].legend()
```